# Vue.js v1 do not work properly with Ajax loaded html file

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, vue.js, axios

I have a small problem related to loaded content over ajax request.

I'm creating a web app that everything is on one page, that is working without any reload or something. So I divided content parts to separate files, and load it over Ajax.

If I load everything into one file without dividing to separate files everything works. But when I made content files and started loading it over Ajax jQuery requests, Vue.js stopped working properly with {{variable}} or other events.

I'm using Vue.js v1, and jQuery for this web app.

Thank you for answers.

Comment: you have to give us the code that you are using,, we have to see it to be able to help you,, share it here or on jsfiddle site

Comment: @KresimirPendic Well, It's a lot of code. I use jQuery request ($( ".layoutCity" ).load("../url/forecast.html");) to add received HTML, and in that HTML I have all {{variables}} used, and they are just loading as HTML. Vue.js is not reading it.

Comment: Vue isn't designed to work the way you're trying to use it: it needs to be able to compile the templates and add its data bindings, you can't just dump template HTML into the page with jquery and expect it to work. (In general you should not be modifying the DOM directly when using Vue or similar frameworks).  Why did you decide to split the content into multiple files?

Comment: @DanielBeck I can post example for you of how to pull different content/data on one page (but with multiple templates) .. is that something that you think would help you?

Comment: @DanielBeck I'm trying to make it more lightweight, and if I use everything in one file it is very slow - 9 sec on the first load and 4 sec on second cached load. Ajax would help me to reduce the big amount of HTML I have, and make easier to work with. Thanks for an answer, I will need to try to reduce load time somehow differently.

Comment: @KresmirPendic I'm not sure, maybe it would help, if I could mount HTML to that template. If yes, It would solve my problem.

Comment: A more common strategy to do this is to keep the templates (which tend to be relatively small) as a single compiled SPA build, then have Vue components load the (relatively high-bandwidth) content as data via AJAX.  Depends on the structure of your site / app of course.

Comment: @DanielBeck for example, my forecast.html template contains 54 lines of HTML including v-html, {{variable}}, and v-for vue.js items. I don't know what I did wrong, but I tried to use all these vue.js functions in route page templates, but it loaded as HTML as well. Maybe you have an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alvaras,

I'm sending you example with one html file that I'm first pulling as template and then attaching vue instance.

I've used `axios` instead of `jQuery`, because it's cool and I've included a bunch of code comments to help you understand what is happening.

**Attention**: only pull template files from servers that are fully trusted!

```js
// let's start by pulling template file and callback our page logic
axios.get('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/4fg33iyn7kie88s/template.html')
  .then( function(res){
    // 1.) render our template on the page
    renderTemplate(res.data);
    // 2.) create Vue instance
    newVueInstance();
  })
  .catch( err );

// create template on our page
function renderTemplate(html){
  var el = document.createElement('div'); // create new 'div'
  document.body.append( el ); // append it to body
  el.innerHTML = html; // and set html
}

// attach new Vue fn
function newVueInstance(){
  // build new vue instance
  var list = new Vue({
    el:"#list",
    data: { items: [], type: 'posts', },
    methods: {
      // let's pull data from remote host (JSON format)
      pullData: function(verb) {
        var url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/" + verb;
        axios.get( url )
          .then( function(res){
            list.items = res.data;
            list.type = verb;
          })
        .catch( err );
      },
    },
  });
}

// handle err
function err(er){ console.log( er );}
```

```css
ul,
li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 5px;
}

li .title,
a {
  font-weight: 900;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios@0.17.1/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.8/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you, but this method is to work with data only, I need to get HTML as well. I use axios to get json data to display info.

Comment: I can easily replace jquery with axios, and we can pull html template as well, Ill update it latter